# how do i change BLE GATT Profile in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, bluetooth-gatt

thanks for reading

im starter in android and ble

just i want to modify BLE's GATT profile ex) UUID, Major, Minor, etc..

i find two Docs
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html

use this two Docs,
can i modify Gatt profile to use BluetoothGatt(it is a class)'s writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)(this is method)??

in BluetoothGattCharacteristic Class, it use UUID but have no reference Major and Minor.

please give some answer to me.